# Issues in a Windows Phone WebApp using JQuery & JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have some issues in a webapp for Windows Phone 8.0 (that runs in WP8.0 and WP8.1). The `index.html` contains:

The source code is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwv9m9bgguv9dw9/Demo_Forum.zip)

(This file contains a directory with HTML, CSS and JS code, a wp80 webapp for testing and a website with code to debug in simulator if needed — this is the version in azure.) You can [see the page in a browser](http://tofas-test.azurewebsites.net/)

Notes:
1.this problem does not occur in iOS or android browser. If you use a WP device open it in IE app and you will see the issues.
2. you can use the WP simulator.

First issue: Header disappears

1. In the main page, I click on the button header to open the left panel:

[image]

2. the panel is opened and the header is missing

[image]

Second issue: The panel does not open when I click on the button for it.

1. click in next page item in left panel to see the next page's content

[image]

2. click on header button to try to open the left panel

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: i reported this error has a bug in github!

Comment: A couple of things: 1. Include the/a `jquery.min.js` file before the `jquery.mobile.min.js` script as it's required by jQuery mobile. 2. Post the code that's in the zipped Dropbox file as part of the question. 3. Crop your images to show only the relevant portions (instead of full screenshots) as scrolling down to see all of them is going to annoy anyone who looks at them.

Comment: Hi, I am using JQuery mobile for my mobile application and I am facing the same issue. Any idea if this has been fixed or is there a workaround for it.I am using JQuery mobile 1.4.5.Thanks in advance

Comment: it was reported as a bug, if I am not wrong! See the original project